# Dynamic Grouping and aggregation in Spark Scala/Python

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

Given a DataFrame:

```
_________________________________________________________
|Date    |Col1   |Col2   |Col3   |Col4   |Col6   |Metric|
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
|1/2/2017|Dog    |Collie |Fruit  |Apple  |Gala   |100   |
|1/2/2017|Dog    |Mixed  |Fruit  |Apple  |Fuji   |100   |
|1/2/2017|Cat    |Persian|Fruit  |Orange |Navel  |100   |
|1/2/2017|Horse  |Arabian|Veg    |Potato |Red    |100   |
|1/2/2017|Cow    |Angus  |Veg    |Potato |Russet |100   |
|2/2/2017|Cow    |Jersey |Fruit  |Apple  |Gala   |100   |
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

And a list of column groups (available at run-time):

```
("Col1","Col1,Col2", "Col1,Col3,Col4")
```

I'd like to output to be the following DataFrame:

```
_________________________________________________
Date    |Grouping       |Value           |Metric|
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1/2/2017|Col1           |Dog             |200   |
1/2/2017|Col1           |Cat             |100   |
1/2/2017|Col1           |Horse           |100   |
1/2/2017|Col1           |Cow             |100   |
1/2/2017|Col1#Col2      |Dog#Collie      |100   |
1/2/2017|Col1#Col2      |Dog#Mixed       |100   |
1/2/2017|Col1#Col3#Col4 |Dog#Fruit#Apple |100   |
......
2/2/2017|Col1           |Dog             |100   |
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

While this is pretty straight-forward if the grouping is known at compile-time, I'd like to create the output DataFrame based on input from a config file.

Comment: Your process from hierarchies to output is not understood, can you elaborate on that a little bit? what is hierarchies?

Comment: I've updated the question to be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a complete solution, but some pieces.  First, I think you have to build up the final dataset by creating one for each column group and then `union`ing them together.  Maybe there's a way to do multiple groupBy aggregations in a single operation, but I don't know it.  So, what follows has to be iterated over each group of columns.

Given a column group string, do something like

```
val cols = colGroup.split(",")
```

Then

```
val groupingCol = lit(cols.mkString("#")).as("Grouping")
val valueCol = ((cols map col) reduce ((c1, c2) => concat(c1, lit("#"),c2))).as("Value")`
```

will get you set up with `Column`s that produce your grouping literal and grouped value.  Finally, a query like

```
ds.groupBy("Date", cols: _*).sum("Metric").
    select(col("Date"), groupingCol, valueCol, col("sum(Metric)").as("Metric"))
```

should get you the result for this grouping.

Comment: This works! The rest of the code for iteration and union is trivial :)